# search function query linq

Tags: c#, linq

Currently im trying to get a search function query working. Im searching a table called "track" my input is a Searchfield.
track table has : Title , artist and album. I am able to search "michael jackson" as artist or "beat it" will work aswell but i cant get it to work "michael jackson beat it" so i bassicly want it to search both title and artist at the same time.
my current query

```
Db.From<Track>()
  .Where(q => q.Title.Contains(request.Trackname) || 
              q.Artist.Contains(request.Trackname) || 
              q.Album.Contains(request.Trackname))
  .Limit(20);
```

would appriciate some help

Comment: You need to split the input to search both fields, or combine the columns ie `(q.Artist + " " + q.Title).Contains(request.TrackName);`

Comment: You should split your input string and search each part individually. You can decide if you want AND or OR rules to apply. It is common to allow quote to enforce certain phrases to be processed as one, such as `"Michael Jackson" "Beat It"` which would search as 2 blocks of text

Comment: Shouldn't be `request.Trackname.Contains(q.Title)...` ?

Comment: (1) are you allowing mixed word order? e.g. should `"Jackson Michael"` return results? how about `"michael beat jackson it"`? (2) are you expecting to get partial queries, e.g. `"Michael Jack"` or `"Jackson Mich"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to split each word of the search keyword entered by user and then search those individually,

1. Firstly match for exact words
2. Then for Partial matches

Also using `Distinct` is required to eliminate duplicate records

```
var searchStrings = request.TrackName.Split(' ').ToList();

Db.From<Track>()
  .Where(q => 
              request.TrackName.Equals(q.Album) ||
              request.TrackName.Equals(q.Artist) ||
              request.TrackName.Equals(q.Title) ||
              request.TrackName.IndexOf(q.Album) > 0 ||
              request.TrackName.IndexOf(q.Artist) > 0 ||
              request.TrackName.IndexOf(q.Title) > 0 ||
              searchStrings.Any(x => x.Equals(q.Title)) || 
              searchStrings.Any(x => x.Equals(q.Artist)) || 
              searchStrings.Any(x => x.Equals(q.Album)))
  .Distinct()
  .Limit(20);
```

Comment: `searchStrings.Contains(q.Artist)` and `searchStrings.Any(x => x.Equals(q.Artist))` (and all other pairs) are equivalent, you don't need to add both since their outcome is exactly the same.

Comment: This also suffers from the same problem as the other answer: you break the query into words (`["Michael", "Jackson", "Beat", "It" ]`). None of these words will ever match the artist's full name (`"Michael Jackson"`)

Comment: @Flater Check now.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can get the most expected result like this way,

Split the input search then match it with Title,Artist,Album.

```
        string search ="michael jackson beat it";

            var searchKeys = search.split(' ');

           Db.From<Track>()
            .Where(q => q.Title.Contains(request.Trackname) || 
              q.Artist.Contains(request.Trackname) || 
              q.Album.Contains(request.Trackname)) ||
              searchKeys.Contains(q.Album) ||
              searchKeys.Contains(q.Artist) ||
              searchKeys.Contains(q.Title) ||
              Array.Exists(searchKeys, z=> q.Title.Contains(z)) ||
              Array.Exists(searchKeys, z=> q.Artist.Contains(z)) ||
              Array.Exists(searchKeys, z=> q.Album.Contains(z))
  .Limit(20);
```

It will give you result in either way if user search like :

- michael jackson beat it
- beat it michael jackson

Comment: This doesn't work. You split the query by whitespace (`["michael", "jackson", "beat", "it"]`. None of these will ever match the artist's full name. `searchKeys.Contains(q.Artist)` will return false even if `q.Artist = "Michael Jackson"`. And `q.Artist.Contains(request.Trackname)` will return false because your search string includes "beat it", which the artist's name does not contain.